# How to post simple string (not dictionary) in alamofire?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have to post raw string at body.
In the usual case, I did this.

```swift
    let parameters = ["asdf": "asdf", "fdsa", "fdsa"]
    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON.......
```

but how to post raw string? (it's not json string. just string.)

```swift
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: "jsut simple string", encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON.......
```

How can I do that??

Comment: You cannot pass `string1` as parameter. The expected argument type is `Dictionary`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alamofire 5 now supports `Encodable` types as parameters. If you want to encode just a `String`, switch to using that form of making a `Request`:

```
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: "just simple string", encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default)
```

Note the `encoder` instead of `encoding` parameter name and new `JSONParameterEncoder` type.

Also, using `responeJSON` is no longer recommended, using `responseDecodable` to produce `Decodable` types would be a better approach.

Comment: This doesn;t work on iOS 12.4.xx  . Error - parameterEncodingFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ParameterEncodingFailureReason.jsonEncodingFailed(error: Swift.EncodingError.invalidValue Top-level String encoded as string JSON fragment.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately iOS <12 doesn't support fragments in `JSONEncoder`. However, the principle is the same.

Comment: Not using a `String` parameter would be the solution, since most backends expect keyed parameters anyway. Otherwise you can manually encode your `URLRequest` before issuing it, or create a custom parameter encoder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below custom encoding to send single value in param, and pass `[:]` empty dictionary in parameter

```
struct SingleValueEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    private let value: String

    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = urlRequest.urlRequest

        let data = value.data(using: .utf8)!

        if urlRequest?.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
            urlRequest?.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }

        urlRequest?.httpBody = data

        return urlRequest!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Alamofire request, the `Parameters` is `dictionary`

```
/// A dictionary of parameters to apply to a `URLRequest`.
public typealias Parameters = [String: Any]
```